# Distributed Java RMI in VM(s)

Tags: java, linux, rmi

I tried to create Java RMI program and everything goes very well when I used one machine or I used host and VM. However, the programs are not working when I run it on two different VM(s).

on VM1, I run 'rmiregistry' and 'java server ' - Works

on VM2, I run 'java client ' - **ERROR**

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception
>   creating connection to: 192.168.122.30; nested exception is: 
>     java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)

I have tried from another stackoverflow thread and other sources:

1. Put the specific port under the implementation.java 'super()'
2. Use the hostname@
3. Inject the ipaddress in code
4. Run server using -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=

Still isnt working.

**SSH, telnet, ping, and traceroute are working**

**[SOLVED]**

To get the vm talking each other, the programs do not have any problems but the firewall on vm(s) is. So before running the programs, please make sure, the firewalld is disabled and stop running. Then, It will work. 
Run this command in the vm(s)

```
systemctl status firewalld   
systemctl disable firewalld   
systemctl stop firewalld   
systemctl status firewalld
```

Comment: it seems like RMI protocol is blocked between your VMs. Check what is used JRMP, RMI-IIOP, t3(Weblogic) etc... and is it allowed to use.  a little bit of info: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=23444

Comment: @Vadim RMI uses tcp as its protocol. How can we know if its blocked or not? and how to unblock it?

Comment: TCP is in lower level. RMI is the next. i.e. udp, ssh, http, telnet, t3, IIOP, ftp etc. all of them run over tcp. I'm not a network guy, sorry. It is just a clue... I know that UDP as example can be blocked...

Comment: 'No route to host' is an error in your IP routing table. It has nothing whatsoever to do with protocol blocking. @Vadim

Comment: This is not an RMI coding problem. Possibly an instance of [RMI FAQ item #A.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain). Or else an IP routing table problem.